# How do I get a value of an protected item inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array:-

```
$result =  Array
(

    [0] => Objects\Update Object
        (
            [items:protected] => Array(
                  [update_id] => 500206735 
                  [message] => Objects\Message Object ( 
                       [word] =>hello
                  )

            )

        )
)
```

I want to get  the value in `[word]`

I tried:-  `$result[0]->['items:protected']['messages']->['word']`

but it didn't work . any ideas ?

Comment: `$result[0]->items['message']->word`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution ,

if there are protected items in an array ,

either we have to declare get methods inside the class itself or
 not to declare the items as protected in the first place. So if we made get methods , the answer will be ,

`$result[0]->getMessage()->word`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need square braces to access properties of objects. Try:

```
$result[0]->items['messages']->word
```

Remember to check that the properties are public, and check for the attributes/array keys before accessing to prevent errors.

Comment: actually it was items:protected instead of items , I thought it's just a name and changed it in the question , will this make a difference ? I mean still will I be able to access the same way ?